# Shortlist return URL

Tags: plugin-shortlist

working with the [Shortlist plugin](https://transition.topshelfcraft.com/software/craft/shortlist/overview) for Craft.

I'm trying to set the return URL after someone adds an item to their shortlist.

i assume thats what this parameter is for...

```
<a href="{{ item.addActionUrl({ 'return' : 'my-page-i-want-to-go-to' }) }}">add item</a>
```

however that takes the user to a 404 page with the url of

```
mydomain.com/index.php/actions/shortlist/item/my-page-i-want-to-go-to
```

any ideas?

Comment: How about something like `<a href="{{ item.addActionUrl({ 'return' : url('my-page-i-want-to-go-to') }) }}">add item</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments on the Question, the solution here is to enclose your desired path with a `url()` function like so:

```
<a href="{{ item.addActionUrl({ 'return' : url('my-page-i-want-to-go-to') }) }}">add item</a>
```

The `url()` function will take your current [SiteURL](https://craftcms.com/support/site-url) and append the provided path. You can view the offical documentation about `url()` [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/functions.html#url).